# htaccess redirect www to non-www without file extension .php

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to redirect with .htaccess from non-www to www . Redirection works fine, however the .php extension of the URI is shown when redirecting from non-www to www. For example  mydomain.com/info becomes [www.mydomain.com/info.php](http://www.mydomain.com/info.php)

How can I get rid of the .php extension when redirecting? Thanks!

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Try and replace the `%{REQUEST_URI}` part with `/$1` (back reference to what your pattern captures.)

Comment: Have a try using the flags `[R=301,END]` instead of `[L,R=301]` ...

Comment: with ```/$1``` it directly refers back to the main domain e.g. example.com/info/dates becomes www.example.com/dates.php, and

```[R=301,END]``` does not change anything, it redirects with .php extension to www.example.com/info/dates.php

Answer (score 0):

it works with that code to remove the .php extension also after redirecting

```
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L,NE]
```